# Delete column if colname can't be found in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have a data frame looking similar to the one below.

```
set.seed(12)

size <- sample(100:1000, 7)
var <- c("V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9")
dist <- matrix(runif(100), nrow = 7, ncol = 7)
diag(dist) <- 0

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, size, dist))
```

This leads to a dataset looking like this:

```
  var size                  V3                V4                 V5                V6                V7                 V8                V9
1  V3  549                   0 0.264918377622962  0.787836347473785 0.439429325051606 0.941087544662878   0.97763589094393 0.774718186818063
2  V4  445  0.0228777434676886                 0 0.0978530396241695 0.669819295872003 0.693911424372345  0.197649595327675 0.394586439244449
3  V5  435 0.00832482660189271 0.457607151241973                  0 0.240883231163025 0.843702238984406  0.844225987326354 0.361513090785593
4  V6  346   0.392697197152302 0.540707547217607  0.217823043232784                 0 0.384644460165873 0.0950279189273715 0.421090044546872
5  V7  958   0.813880559289828 0.665679829893634  0.267943592974916 0.882756386883557                 0  0.381151003297418 0.322011524345726
6  V8  273    0.37624845537357 0.112698937533423  0.504767951788381 0.814063254510984  0.58848182996735                  0 0.552160830702633
```

I want to delete the columns whose column-name can't be found in the variable `var` (in this case the column with the name `V9`). I also want to keep the two first columns, `var` and `size`.  This lead to a data set looks like this:

```
  var size                  V3                V4                 V5                V6                V7                 V8
1  V3  549                   0 0.264918377622962  0.787836347473785 0.439429325051606 0.941087544662878   0.97763589094393 
2  V4  445  0.0228777434676886                 0 0.0978530396241695 0.669819295872003 0.693911424372345  0.197649595327675 
3  V5  435 0.00832482660189271 0.457607151241973                  0 0.240883231163025 0.843702238984406  0.844225987326354 
4  V6  346   0.392697197152302 0.540707547217607  0.217823043232784                 0 0.384644460165873 0.0950279189273715 
5  V7  958   0.813880559289828 0.665679829893634  0.267943592974916 0.882756386883557                 0  0.381151003297418 
6  V8  273    0.37624845537357 0.112698937533423  0.504767951788381 0.814063254510984  0.58848182996735                  0
```

Comment: The first two columns are actually not mentioned in `var` either.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, of course, I want to keep the two first columns! :)

Comment: When I run the code, I don't get the first dataframe you posted. For me it returns a 7x9 dataframe. Could you double check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `%in%` to find which variables to keep, then manually replace the first two values with `TRUE`.

```
col.keep <- colnames(df) %in% df$var
col.keep[1:2] <- TRUE
df2 <- df[col.keep]
```

If you don't know the position of `df$var` and `df$size`, manually bind them in.

```
col.keep <- colnames(df) %in% df$var
df3 <- cbind(df$var, df$size, df[col.keep])
```

Comment: If you're using the `tidyverse`, you can use `bind_cols()` instead of `cbind()`. Slightly faster, safer.

Comment: Why not just `df[names(df) %in% c("var", "size", df$var)]`?

Comment: I think then you have to unfactor `df$var` or `c()` does funky things.

Comment: `df2 <- df[names(df) %in% c("var", "size", as.character(df$var))]` works, though!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `pivot_longer` and bring with it the columns V* into rows. Then you can just filter for those columns and pivot back.